# How can I center a div with a fixed width so that it scrolls horizontally and stays centered responsively when the div is wider than the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this working the way I want it to, except that I need it to stay centered, so that the green rectangle is in the center of the browser (until the user scrolls) when the browser width is between 835px - 320px.

I'd like to get this figured out with CSS, but I'm not opposed to a JavaScript solution.

I'm pretty new to posting questions on stackoverflow, so I apologize in advance if I'm not clear enough or if I've provided too much or not enough information.

Thank you in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.bottles-container-mobile .container-fluid {
    overflow: auto;
    background: #ccc;
}

.product_map_image_mobile {
    width: 835px;
    height: 359px;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
}

.product_map_image_mobile .product_map_link_mobile {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    text-indent: -999em;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.product_map_image_mobile #product_map_link_mobile_0 {
    width: 77px;
    height: 193px;
    top: 117px;
    left: 20px;
    background:blue;
}

.product_map_image_mobile #product_map_link_mobile_1 {
    width: 88px;
    height: 202px;
    top: 113px;
    left: 97px;
    background:red;
}

.product_map_image_mobile #product_map_link_mobile_2 {
    width: 91px;
    height: 213px;
    top: 106px;
    left: 187px;
    background:orange
}

.product_map_image_mobile #product_map_link_mobile_3 {
    width: 89px;
    height: 218px;
    top: 104px;
    left: 279px;
    background:purple;
}

.product_map_image_mobile #product_map_link_mobile_4 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 233px;
    top: 94px;
    left: 369px;
    background:green;
}

.product_map_image_mobile #product_map_link_mobile_5 {
    width: 91px;
    height: 219px;
    top: 104px;
    left: 470px;
    background:orange;
}

.product_map_image_mobile #product_map_link_mobile_6 {
    width: 86px;
    height: 216px;
    top: 104px;
    left: 562px;
    background:purple;
}

.product_map_image_mobile #product_map_link_mobile_7 {
    width: 91px;
    height: 211px;
    top: 106px;
    left: 649px;
    background:gray;
}

.product_map_image_mobile #product_map_link_mobile_8 {
    width: 79px;
    height: 194px;
    top: 117px;
    left: 740px;
    background:blue;
}


</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="bottles-container-mobile">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="product-solutions-green-bar-mobile">
                    <div class="product_map_image_mobile">
                        <a class="product_map_link_mobile" id="product_map_link_mobile_0" title="" href="#"></a>
                        <a class="product_map_link_mobile" id="product_map_link_mobile_1" title="" href="#"></a>
                        <a class="product_map_link_mobile" id="product_map_link_mobile_2" title="" href="#"></a>
                        <a class="product_map_link_mobile" id="product_map_link_mobile_3" title="" href="#"></a>
                        <a class="product_map_link_mobile" id="product_map_link_mobile_4" title="" href="#"></a>
                        <a class="product_map_link_mobile" id="product_map_link_mobile_5" title="" href="#"></a>
                        <a class="product_map_link_mobile" id="product_map_link_mobile_6" title="" href="#"></a>
                        <a class="product_map_link_mobile" id="product_map_link_mobile_7" title="" href="#"></a>
                        <a class="product_map_link_mobile" id="product_map_link_mobile_8" title="" href="#"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here is the code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewmowder/k5NKT/

Comment: You can use @media to detect the screen width and adapt the div width.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```
@media screen and(max-width:835px) and (min-width:320px) {
    .product_map_image_mobile {
        width: new_widthpx;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Codel96. I'm using media queries in the site itself, but what I'm needing here is for the width of .product_map_image_mobile to always remain at a width of 835px, but to have it center within the browser window when the browser is less than 835px wide.

Comment: Mmmh, sorry if I misunderstood. But margin: auto doesn't work? I saw that you are using it so I think it is not what you're looking for but I want to be sure.

Comment: no worries. yeah, I can't get margin: auto to work in this situation. The div sticks to the left edge of the browser window upon resizing. I thought this could be pulled off with CSS, but maybe I need to look into a JavaScript solution.

Comment: Do you have to use position:absolute; and position:relative; or could you use simple "float:left" with margin?

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work that way either, unfortunately.

Comment: My friend Cliff figured out a JavaScript solution that's going to work. I just need to tweak the styling a bit so that the green square hits dead center. http://jsfiddle.net/k5NKT/1/